# How to save current time in joomla database according to timezone in joomla configuration?

Tags: joomla

> I want to save current time in joomla according to the configuration
>   of joomla server timezone. Because my host provider has set timezone
>   to africa/capetown but I need to get current time of timezone
>   asia/kolkata which I have set backend server configuration. When I
>   used Jdate class then It given time according timezone africa/capetown
>   how can I get time in joomla according to joomla configuration time
>   zone Asia/kolkata.

Comment: why don't you store UTC dates in the database and let the view decide the timezone? that will be more flexible and easy to move, especially when your information scales across timezones

Comment: Can you explain your comment?

Comment: That if you save dates in UTC (so global configuration-location settings-universal time) and only force the timezone when reading them it will be easier such as `$jdate=JFactory::getDate($dbDateValue,'asia/kolkata'); `

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
//get Configuration of joomla site    
  $config = JFactory::getConfig();  

//get offset of joomla like asia/kolkata 
  $site_offset = $config->get('offset'); 

//get instance of joomla JDate Class                                      
  $jdate=JFactory::getDate('now',$site_offset);     
// first argument now give me current time-stamp you also can pass time-stamp   

// second parameter is offset i.e. time zone like asia/kolkata   
  $jdate->format('Y-m-d H:i:s',true); 
//get converted time as your joomla configuration
```